# Order Mongoid results by dynamic, user-specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I have a Mongoid model, and I'd like to order the results by a score that's calculated between the model and `current_user` in real time. Suppose `Thing` has an instance method `match_score`:

```
  def match_score(user) #can be user object too
    score = 100
    score -= 5 if user.min_price && !(price < user.min_price)
    score -= 10 if user.max_price && !(price > user.max_price)
    #... bunch of other factors...
    return [score, 0].max
  end
```

Is it possible to sort the results of any query by the value returned for a particular user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support arbitrary expressions in sorting. Basically, you only can specify a field and a direction (asc/desc).

With such complicated sorting logic as yours, the only way is to do it in the app. Or look at another data store.

Comment: Just a minor nitpic: Switching the datastore won't save your from calculating the score for every combination of Thing/User.

Comment: Yes, but with mysql (for example), one can do it in the query, without precalculation. I don't know if it's possible to efficiently precalculate this.